# Multiple meta_key in one global $wpdb;

Tags: php, functions, mysql

I have this code which works great:

```
global $wpdb;

$ticker_tag = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT meta_value, COUNT(*) AS c 

FROM $wpdb->postmeta 

WHERE meta_key = 'ticker'   

GROUP BY meta_value 

ORDER BY c DESC" );
```

Is there any way to add two meta_key values?

I have tried:

```
WHERE meta_key = 'ticker', 'ticker2'
```

also tried this:

```
WHERE meta_key = 'ticker' AND 'ticker2'
```

but none of them works.

Comment: This is just SQL, so not specific to Wordpresss, but you want one meta key OR the other. A result can’t have both. So use OR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `WHERE meta_key = 'ticker' OR meta_key = 'ticker2'`

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm.